# Python - How to pass blank argument - sometimes I want blank cc for an email

Tags: python, email, argv

I am using `exe`c command to call python script with arguments to send email. Sometimes I want to keep `cc` as blank but when I do that I get error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I pass blank `cc` as an argument to a python script ?

```
FileName - attachment <br/>
Subject - message body <br/>
rec_list - 'To' list <br/>
Filepath - location of file to attach <br/>
Email_CC - 'CC' list  - *`this is null or blank`* <br/>
Email_BCC - 'BCC' list <br/>

$G_SendMail_Return=exec('cmd.exe','[$GV_FileName3]'||' '||'[$G_Subject]'||' '||'[$G_Rec_List]'||' '|| '[$GV_Filepath]'||' '|| '[$G_Email_CC]'||' '|| '[$G_Email_BCC]' ,8);
```

Code

```
import smtplib <br/>
from email.mime.text import MIMEText <br/>
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart <br/>
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase <br/>
from email import encoders <br/>
import os.path <br/>
import sys <br/>

arg1 = sys.argv[1]; <br/>
arg2 = sys.argv[2]; <br/>
arg3 = sys.argv[3]; <br/>
arg4 = sys.argv[4]; <br/>
arg5 = sys.argv[5]; <br/>
```

Error:

```
sys.argv[5];  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please show your code where you get this error

Comment: You should check [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `len(sys.argv)` to count how many input arguments you actually get. And make your desired argument blank using something like this (just an example, adjust by your situation):

```
arg5 = sys.argv[5] if len(sys.argv) >= 6 else ""
```